# Emitting the response from the elastic4s subscriber back to the akka-stream

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, akka, akka-stream, elastic4s

I am currently building a solution to stream data from mongoDb to elasticsearch.
My goal is to keep track of all successful transmitted items to elasticsearch.
I am using akka-streams and elastic4s. Currently the streaming into es looks like this

```
val esSubscriber: BulkIndexingSubscriber[CustomT] = esClient.subscriber[CustomT](
    batchSize = batchSize,
    completionFn = { () => elasticFinishPromise.success(()); ()},
    errorFn = { (t: Throwable) => elasticFinishPromise.failure(t); ()},
    concurrentRequests = concurrentRequests
    )
val esSink: Sink[CustomT, NotUsed] = Sink.fromSubscriber(esSubscriber)
```

And from my source something like this:

```
val a: [NotUsed] = mongoSrc
  .via(some operations..)
  .to(esSink)
  .run()
```

Now everything works fine and right now I am logging for example item count with a second sink. But I would rather log the items really transmitted to elasticsearch.
The elastic4s subscriber offers a `listener: ResponseListener` with `onAck(): Unit` and `onFailure(): Unit` and I would love to get this information back into the stream like this

```
val mongoSrc: [Source..]
val doStuff: [Flow..]
val esSink: [Flow..] //now as flow instead of sink
val logSink: [Sink[Int...]] //now gets for example a 1 for each successful transported item

mongoSrc ~> doStuff ~> esSink ~> logSink
```

How would I implement that? Do I need a custom stage which buffers the elements of the `onAck` and the `onFailure`? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The Akka Streams reactive-kafka driver does something like this, maybe it could be inspirational to look at those sources: https://github.com/akka/reactive-kafka (the ProducerStage especially)

Comment: thank you that looks pretty helpful! Trying this tomorrow

Comment: Could you create another stream which is populated via the onAck method?

Comment: @monkjack yes that is exactly what I am doing now, I created another Stream with a source.queue and push to it on onAck.

Answer (score 1):

You could 'flowify' your `Subscriber[T]` sink by leveraging `Flow.fromSinkAndSource`. Check out the 'Composite Flow (from Sink and Source)' illustration from [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.8/scala/stream/stream-composition.html).

In this case, you would be attaching your custom actorPublisher as a source and sending it messages from `onAck()`.

Since you asked for an easier way:

```
val doStuff = Flow[DocToIndex]
                .grouped(batchSize)
                .mapAsync(concurrentRequests)(bulkopFuture)
```

In a nutshell and all useful abstractions aside, elastic4s subscriber is just [a bulk update request](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/blob/master/elastic4s-streams/src/main/scala/com/sksamuel/elastic4s/streams/BulkIndexingSubscriber.scala#L226).

Comment: Note that now you don't need `esSink` juncture. Your graph will look like `mongoSrc ~> doStuff ~> logSink`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your approach with the actorPublisher would work fine. I guess it would have to be an pre materialization actorPublisher, because with the source.queue and the composite flow I run into the problem, that I first get the source.queue when the graph is already materialized and thats to late to inject it into the elastic4s subscriber.
Now I just create another Stream and let the onAck method push to the source.queue and everything works fine, also I am still not 100% happy with the solution and would prefer a composite flow.